# What does it mean to run PHP in quiet mode?

Tags: php

You can run PHP with the `-q` command line switch. The manual only say:

> Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header
>   output (CGI only).

What does that actually mean in practical terms?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This only concerns the PHP interpreter built against the CGI SAPI. This version sends a few basic HTTP headers before any actual output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3
Content-type: text/html

"(echo) What I actually wanted to have"
```

So basically the `-q` commandline flag prevents any `header()` from being written to stdout.

The purpose is to use the php-cgi binary in lieu of the php CLI variant for console scripts. Usually you see following shebang in such scripts to force php-cgi to behave like the -cli version:

```
#!/usr/bin/php-cgi -qC
```

Answer (score 7):

As you can see with `-q` key php suppresses to send headers (added some new lines in the output though to make it more readable):

```
zerkms@l12 ~ $ cat file.php
<?php

header('Location: http://stackoverflow.com');

echo 42;

zerkms@l12 ~ $ php file.php
Status: 302 Moved Temporarily
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Location: http://stackoverflow.com
Content-type: text/html

42

zerkms@l12 ~ $ php -q file.php
42
```