# Can I pass cookies to a PHP script from bash CGI?

Tags: php, bash, cgi

I would like to start a PHP script from a bash CGI script in such a way that the PHP script can access the same session, i.e., the cookies. Is this possible?

Comment: If you know session id you could just specify `session_id('id here');` right before `session_start()`

Comment: Did you invoke the `php-cgi` binary? That should inherit the CGI environment and accept the `HTTP_COOKIE` env variable.

Comment: @zerkms I tried that. According to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) setting session_id creates new cookies even if it exists.

Comment: @mario That sounds good, but it's behaving very strangely, it's almost as if it's cating the files it's being run in rather running the named php script.

Comment: You need to adapt SCRIPT_FILENAME of course.

Comment: @mario Thanks, if you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it. There isn't an option to skip the HTTP header is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `php-cgi` binary. If invoked from another CGI script it inherits the environment, thus all `HTTP_*` variables, including the cookies. There are a few setup caveats:

- `SCRIPT_FILENAME` needs to be adapted to the PHP script. The `php-cgi` binary ignores the file argument otherwise.
- Likewise adapt `SCRIPT_NAME` and eventually `REQUEST_URI`
- You also need `REDIRECT_STATUS=200` [depending on config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047426/call-php-from-virtual-custom-web-server/7047581#7047581).
- This works for GET rquests, repiping POST data is often an issue.

To suppress the php-cgi  header output, you can possibly [invoke it with `-q`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777792/what-does-it-mean-to-run-php-in-quiet-mode/5777845#5777845) however. That shouldn't impair the CGI input, just the response.

Comment: The php-cgi call from my bash cgi script does not seem to be processing any parameters I give it (eg, -q). Any ideas?

Comment: It's possible that it ignores it for later php-cgi versions and when a full CGI environment is present. In that case you need to post-filter it. (There is also a `cgi.nph` setting, but I doubt it would help. I can't really locate either in the cgi_main.c source)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just use curl, looks like it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Curl can do it, although via apache rather than directly:

```
curl -sb "$HTTP_COOKIE" http://example.com/script.php
```

Although at the moment it doesn't seem to be reproducing carriage returns.