# PHPAGI: Exec format error

Tags: php, linux, asterisk, agi

Encountering a problem when running phpagi:

```
-- Executing [123@DLPN_C:1] AGI("SIP/1000-00000001", "hello_world.php") in new stack
-- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/hello_world.php
hello_world.php: Failed to execute '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/hello_world.php': Exec format error
-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1000-00000001' status is 'UNKNOWN' Scheduling destruction of SIP dialog '343930130' in 32000 ms (Method: INVITE)
```

From command line:

```
root@asterisk-test:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin# php5 -q hello_world.php 
#!/usr/bin/php5 -q
```

Additional info:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root       757 Mar 29 19:32 hello_world.php
drwxrwxr-x  4 root     root      4096 Mar 29 19:44 phpagi
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     25079 Sep 30  2010 phpagi-asmanager.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root      2322 Sep 30  2010 phpagi-fastagi.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root     root     67615 Sep 30  2010 phpagi.php
```

Source of hello world: http://www.eder.us/projects/phpagi/phpagi/api-docs/__examplesource/exsource_home_html_projects_phpagi_phpagi_examples_dtmf.php_acb7257145e4a5249182c8373cd8e848.html

Comment: In your source `/usr/local/bin/php` and in your example `/usr/bin/php5`, and what is the `-q` switch?

Comment: Quiet mode. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777792/what-does-it-mean-to-run-php-in-quiet-mode

Answer (score 5):

The Exec Format Error is from `/bin/bash`, asterisk executes `hello_world.php` as a bash script.

**shebang**

If you add a correct [shebang](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php#example-372), the script get executed by the given PHP intepreter.
The first Line tells the System which program should run the script.

`#!/usr/bin/env php`

To test your shebang, execute the script itself, not by PHP:
    `root@asterisk-test:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin# ./hello_world.php`

Make sure it is executable with:
    `root@asterisk-test:/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin# chmod +x hello_world.php`

**alternative wrapper**

Create a bash script that executes the PHP script.

example hello_world.sh:
  `/usr/bin/php hello_world.php`

and call it in the Dialplan `AGI("hello_world.sh")`.

Make sure the shellscript is executable `chmod +x hello_world.sh`.

Comment: ./hello_world.php did not work, but php hello_world.php worked.

Comment: `./hello_world.php` must work to get it executed by asterisk, you should adjust the shebang to the binary that is used by php, which you can see by executing `which php` and make sure it is executable.

Comment: I have /usr/bin/php and /usr/bin/php5. php is a link to php5.

Comment: try `#!/usr/bin/env php` and is `hello_world.php` executable? I updated my answer, try a alternative wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

I added following line on top script to get it working for me

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

Answer (score 1):

You issue is not asterisk issue,but general linux one.

Please try from your command line following:

```
su asterisk -c "/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/hello_world.php"
```

Most likly reasons: php path is incorrect or selinux enabled and not configured.

Comment: check that you have /usr/bin/text2wave and it is exutable.

Comment: I do. text2wave --help
text2wave [options] textfile
  Convert a textfile to a waveform

Comment: have you checked selinux? have you tried DISABLE it? that vary depend of your OS, usualy /etc/sysconfig/selinux (need restart after change)

Comment: The host is debian. SELinux is not enabled.

Comment: try do following: 1) stop asterisk. 2) start it using "asterisk -vvvc" 3) agi set debug on, 4) re-check output.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your `extensions.conf` or `extensions_custom.conf`, if the extension and priority are not continuous also this error will occur.

please check the below example:

```
[context]
exten => 1,1,Answer()
exten => 1,2,AGI(your-agi-script)
exten => 1,3,Hangup()
```