# Asterisk Failed to execute '/usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/call_handle.php': Permission denied

Tags: php, linux, asterisk, permission-denied, agi

Server: Ubunto

Asterisk Version: 11.x

Directory: /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/
File: call_handle.php

Directory Permission: 755 root root
File Permission: 755 root root

> **asterisk.conf**

```
astagidir => /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin
```

> **extensions.conf**

```
same  => n,AGI(call_handle.php)
```

When I dial any number this AGI PHP Script is run.
But, It will give me this message in asterisk console.

```
Asterisk Failed to execute '/usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/call_handle.php': Permission denied
```

I am not sure why this message is comes up. It has **execute** permission with **ROOT** user

Comment: This may be off-topic because its not about programming or development. Perhaps you should ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: It is related to server fault and asterisk programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer myself:
Set PHP Envirement in my php script and it will run by asterisk.

I have set following in my php file at first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Reff: [PHPAGI: Exec format error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713359/phpagi-exec-format-error)

Answer (score 3):

The probable issue seems to be with the file ('/usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/call_handle.php') not falling in the user group of Asterisk daemon that is asterisk:asterisk

That is to say - Asterisk daemon should have the ownership of this file.

Secondly, there is also a possibility that the user who is actually running this Asterisk daemon is not having the execute permission of this daemon.It should be there.

Comment: I have already checked with asterisk:asterisk user, group changed to that directory and files but not success. But, It may be need to check with user permission for asterisk

Comment: Yes, as i said the second possibility is of the user who is actually running this Asterisk daemon is not having the execute permission of this daemon.It should be there. Do check and update here

Comment: I got the same error.
the problem was that deamon asterisk was running with a diferent user  (wasn't asterisk) and the ownership of the folders (/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/ and /var/lib/asterisk/) were for asterisk:asterisk
the solutions was to change the ownership for the folders.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure file can be executed

```
chmod a+x /usr/share/asterisk/agi-bin/call_handle.php
```

After that check that selinux  not enabled or setup correctly

Disable selinux on Centos/Redhat

```
 echo "SELINUX=disabled" > /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

After that need reboot

Comment: FIle Permission: `-rwxrwxrwx 1 asterisk asterisk  1404 Jan 17 14:27 call_handle.php`

I am using Ubuntu as OS

Comment: *"Disable selinux on Centos/Redhat"* - that's OK during development, but its not an acceptable solution in production. But turning it off like that in development makes it painful when the switch to production occurs.

Comment: Selinux really usless thing when  you deal with single asterisk service server. Just becuase you have allow to much to really protect server or disable to much for AGI process working. Also it require high admin skill in selinux, which for sure not topicstarter case.

Comment: Ubuntu's file is /etc/selinux/config