# Php daemon -q switch

Tags: php

In XAMPP, in order to run a php daemon we use:

```
php -q htdocs\folder1\folder2\daemon.php
```

What is the meaning of `-q`? Are there any more commands like this I need to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See command line options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

> -q | --no-header | Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

Comment: any further explanations? i am new

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777792/what-does-it-mean-to-run-php-in-quiet-mode