# What is the meaning of -q in the following scripts? What differences will it make running without it?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am running this script,

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/app_folder/artisan queue:work >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Does this mean, the command will run in queue?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from the `man php` command:

```
-q  Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).
```

See also [What does it mean to run PHP in quiet mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777792/what-does-it-mean-to-run-php-in-quiet-mode)

Answer (score 1):

From the manual of php you can found this:

> -q
>   Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).

Answer (score 1):

It's an option for the php command, you can read on the manual:

> -q :            Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP header output (CGI only).